# IE 9 32 bit and IE 9 64 bit installed but after power outage, IE 32 bit won't run

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-9

I had been using IE 9 32 bit which was pinned to my task bar. After a power outage, I could not open the 32 bit and had to use IE 9 64 bit. How do I get the 32 bit version to run again? My OS is Windows 7 Pro 64 bit.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps try using [Windows' System Restore](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows7/products/features/system-restore) to go back to a point before the power outage?

> System Restore can return your PC's system files and programs to a time when everything was working fine, potentially preventing hours of troubleshooting headaches. It won't affect your documents, pictures, or other data.